# How can I handle different languages when using nimbella commander on Slack?

Tags: nimbella-commander

I want to create a nimbella command but I want my function to respond to Slack appropriately based on the end user language (ie i18n).

How do I know the locale of the end user when I need to program my response so the response is adjusted based on language (ie Spanish, English, etc) and formatting (ie currency).

Comment: You can may be have the user input the language he wants? May be something like the translate command-set: https://github.com/nimbella/command-sets/tree/master/translate ?

Comment: Not a very good user experience, imagine every user needs to put their language in the command. Slack should be sending the locale to the backend

Comment: Thanks for the input. We will try to implement locale and will let you know soon